# Arduino UNo + GPRS/GSM module

Tags: embedded, arduino, hardware, gsm, usart

It may be a very simple question but i need to ask before investing some amount in hardware.As i have read in this  [Arduino link](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield) , Arduino GSm shiled works pretty fine.My question is can we use any other GSM/GPRS module in place of Arduino GSM shiled and GSM library will work equally with that module also.

As per i know, GSM?GPRS module also workover serial protocol with any board, therefore we might use any GSM/GPRS module with TX/RX i.e. USART pin or any other digital pin if we are using serial software library over arduino ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for buying arduinos.cc's official [GSM shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield).
The radio modem it uses is the [M10 by Quectel](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Quectel_M10_datasheet.pdf). As long as you buy another GSM/GPRS shield that uses the same radio modem or that uses a radio modem that uses the same [AT commands](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Quectel_M10_AT_commands.pdf) you will be able to use arduino's gsm library. You could get a cheaper gsm module with the same radio modem, keep in mind you can buy diferent modules, look at [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10138) one for example.
Hope it helps.
Keep updating your progress here it helps everyone.

Comment: While going for this project i need to look after the cost and make this project cost effective. I have a alternate option for GSM module at this link (http://store.extremeelectronics.co.in/GSM-GPRS-Modem-SIM900-KIT.html).Its quite cheaper($39.49), but i need to check its specification with respect to AT commands as refered by you.